# Is it possible to view by date in Picasa?

Tags: software, picasa, date

I'm running Picasa on MacOS, and I can see all of my photos by person and by folder. But can I view them by date? Ideally I'd like to see 'virtual folders' by date YYYY/MM/DD like:

```
2015
  01
    25
```

And then be able to click on it at any level - so clicking on 2015 would show everything in 2015, clicking on 2015/01 would show everything from January 2015.

I thought this would be basic functionality (I don't really care what physical folder/directory they are in) but I don't see it anywhere.

Comment: This question has limited usefulness because Picasa is a discontinued product. Also, given the time that has passed since the question was asked, it is unlikely that anyone is able to answer the question.